# How to add to HttpServletResponse in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, interceptor

I have rest controllers that returns Json response. I have added interceptor which will add some element to the response as shown below.

```
@Override
public void postHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler, final ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long start = (Long) request.getAttribute("_start_time");
    // how do I append to response by the difference of end - start?
    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}
```

If I simply add anything to the response I get the following exception:

There was an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the "end-start" time to response is not the right place. As you may actually end up breaking the JSON response you are sending back.

What you need to do is -

**Option 1 -** Add a response header. Something like this

```
httpServletResponse.addHeader("total-time", "100ms");
```

This way you have the data and you dont have to modifythe response. You can see the header in Firebug.

**Option 2 -** Add the above information in the log file so you dont have to change the servlet response.

Answer (score 2):

On an HttpServletResponse, you can only use one of [getWriter()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) or [getOutputStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29), as indicated in the docs. The exception you're getting is telling you that getOutputStream() was already called, so you're not allowed to call getWriter().